# How can I remotly shutdown a windows machine

Tags: windows, remote

I need to shutdown and / or reboot remote system.
Can this be done remotely without physically being next to the server?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Reboot now:

```
shutdown /r /m \\computername /t 0
```

Shutdown now:

```
shutdown /s /m \\computername /t 0
```

In both examples, change the 0 to a number of seconds to delay if desired.  Plenty of other options you can get from:

```
shutdown /?
```

Comment: You can even get a GUI by using shutdown /i

Answer (score 11):

You might also want to checkout Mark Russinovich's [PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) utility. It's similar to the native Windows shutdown command, but also allows you to logoff the console user or lock the console.

Comment: I also prefer psshutdown over the standard shutdown included in Windows, becausa it allows you to specify a user/password different from the one you are logged.

Comment: +1 this helpped because I needed to use the u/p.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows Remote Desktop hit ctrl+alt+END. Then click the Shut Down button.

Answer (score 2):

Go to command prompt (start > run > cmd) on your workstation... and Type
shutdown -r -m \xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Replace xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx with the IP address or computer name of the remote machine. -r option is for restart, don't use -r if want to just shut down the system.

This can also be very fun

Answer (score 1):

`shutdown -i` gives you a nice simple little GUI for the `shutdown` command where you can target one or more machines, choose shutdown or restart, set the countdown timer etc.
This is the command I always use when I want to restart a remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar post on Stackoverflow and included a reboot script that waits for the server to come back.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56644/how-do-i-detect-if-a-windows-server-is-available-after-a-reboot

Answer (score 1):

I do this at home. Start > Run `cmd.exe` and type in `shutdown -s -t 60` (I always use -t 60 because I'll forget that I need to do something right when I press enter. `shutdown -a` will abort a shutdown if it isn't too late.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Remote Desktop Access shutdown can be done through here.

Comment: Vista, Server 2008, and Win7 remove the shutdown option from the start menu though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [psshutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx) from the SysInternals tools.

Answer (score 0):

Dogbert's Tech Support: do a [Hard Reboot](http://www.babelgum.com/browser.php#play|SEARCH,queryString:dogbert%20hard%20reboot,order:TOP_RATED)

Answer (score 0):

Usage: shutdown [/i | /l | /s | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e] [/f]
    [/m \computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

```
No args    Display help. This is the same as typing /?.
/?         Display help. This is the same as not typing any options.
/i         Display the graphical user interface (GUI).
           This must be the first option.
/l         Log off. This cannot be used with /m or /d options.
/s         Shutdown the computer.
/r         Shutdown and restart the computer.
/g         Shutdown and restart the computer. After the system is
           rebooted, restart any registered applications.
/a         Abort a system shutdown.
           This can only be used during the time-out period.
/p         Turn off the local computer with no time-out or warning.
           Can be used with /d and /f options.
/h         Hibernate the local computer.
           Can be used with the /f option.
/e         Document the reason for an unexpected shutdown of a computer.
/m \\computer Specify the target computer.
/t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
           The valid range is 0-600, with a default of 30.
           Using /t xxx implies the /f option.
/c "comment" Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown.
           Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
/f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
           /f is automatically set when used in conjunction with /t xxx.
/d [p|u:]xx:yy  Provide the reason for the restart or shutdown.
           p indicates that the restart or shutdown is planned.
           u indicates that the reason is user defined.
             if neither p nor u is specified the restart or shutdown is unplanned.
           xx is the major reason number (positive integer less than 256).
           yy is the minor reason number (positive integer less than 65536).
```

Reasons on this computer:
(E = Expected U = Unexpected P = planned, C = customer defined)
Type    Major   Minor   Title

U      0       0       Other (Unplanned)
E       0       0       Other (Unplanned)
E P     0       0       Other (Planned)
 U      0       5       Other Failure: System Unresponsive
E       1       1       Hardware: Maintenance (Unplanned)
E P     1       1       Hardware: Maintenance (Planned)
E       1       2       Hardware: Installation (Unplanned)
E P     1       2       Hardware: Installation (Planned)
  P     2       3       Operating System: Upgrade (Planned)
E       2       4       Operating System: Reconfiguration (Unplanned)
E P     2       4       Operating System: Reconfiguration (Planned)
  P     2       16      Operating System: Service pack (Planned)
        2       17      Operating System: Hot fix (Unplanned)
  P     2       17      Operating System: Hot fix (Planned)
        2       18      Operating System: Security fix (Unplanned)
  P     2       18      Operating System: Security fix (Planned)
E       4       1       Application: Maintenance (Unplanned)
E P     4       1       Application: Maintenance (Planned)
E P     4       2       Application: Installation (Planned)
E       4       5       Application: Unresponsive
E       4       6       Application: Unstable
 U      5       15      System Failure: Stop error
E       5       19      Security issue
 U      5       19      Security issue
E P     5       19      Security issue
E       5       20      Loss of network connectivity (Unplanned)
 U      6       11      Power Failure: Cord Unplugged
 U      6       12      Power Failure: Environment
  P     7       0       Legacy API shutdown